# I can see enemy wards disintegrate when they timeout, is that a bug?

Tags: dota-2

When an enemy ward disintegrates, I can see the "Carcass" of the ward disintegrating. Is this a bug or a feature?
Doesn't matter a lot, but I guess it may help deward future wards.

Comment: This question is likely to be closed as it concerns the game design. If the question is about you seeing ward when they time out, yes its normal, it does that to everyone aswell. If the question is "Why is that so" or "Is that a bug or a feature that you can see they desintegrate", then Im affraid you'll ask to ask Icefrog himself =p.

Comment: it as well tells you that they probably didnt put a new ward at this place. so it's safe.  That's a nice info. Of course they could have a new ward already, but in most cases they don't-

Comment: @WizLiz it's not a bug if it's consistent with WarIII: DotA. However if behaves differently, it might be an addition on purpose and not a bug